# Divide 1 path into all possible ones

Tags: php

It is necessary to build links to catalogs from the path, like breadcrumbs.
That is, the address looks like `folder1\folder2\folder3`
It is necessary to display:

```
folder1 = folder1  
folder2 = folder1\folder2  
folder3 = folder1\folder2\folder3
```

```
$dir = 'folder1\\folder2\\folder3';
$expDir = explode('\\', $dir);
foreach ($expDir as $val) {
   var_dump($val);
}
```

They are parsed only by `folder1 .... folder3` - well, this is already clear, but I just can’t figure out what needs to be done to make exactly the paths to the directories.
That is, take them apart, and then somehow assemble them so that they correspond to the nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple enough, just need to store a temp array with the variable names we want.

```
$dir = 'folder1\\folder2\\folder3';
$expDir = explode('\\', $dir);
$array = [];
$temp = '';
$n = 1;
foreach ($expDir as $val) {
   if($temp != ''){
     $temp .= '/';
   }
   $temp .= $val;
   $array['folder'.$n] = $temp;
   $n++;
}
extract($array);
//$folder1 == 'folder1';
//$folder2 == 'folder1/folder2;
//$folder3 == 'folder1/folder2/folder3;
```